# What ports do I need to open when setting up a mining pool

Tags: go-ethereum, mining-pools

I am setting up a pool as a VM on my home computer using the instructions provided by https://github.com/sammy007/open-ethereum-pool/
I have followed the instructions and managed to get a test miner connect to it in the local environment but I am having issues connecting an external test miner. Also externally I am getting the Stats API not available message. Locally the page loads fine.

I have mapped the following ports
84 maps to 80 (My isp won’t allow 80)
8888
8008
8084 (I have to change the api port as 8080 was being used)
8545 (I understand opening this is a security risk but I am not sure)
6379
Are there any other ports that I need to open allow the pool to work?

Answer (score 0):

You have to be aware that remapping ports that are required open inside your computer or home-network won't get you network connectivity.

That means: if the rest of the network expect to find your mining server at "port 80" - as per default http, running it on your computer on port 80, and them routing port 84 from the Internet to your port 80 just won't do anything.

What might help you there is that for the http protocol, you can pass the port number along with the address - just like in `http://127.0.0.1:8180` to run on port 8180 rather than 80.

Otherwise if your ISP won't allow incoming connection on needed ports, you will have to use a tunneling service, such as the provided by https://ngrok.com/ to your localhost.